# Splitting polygons with lines not working for polygons that intersect with multiple lines [QGIS]

Tags: qgis, spatial-join, splitting, polygon-creation

The 'Split with Lines' tool in QGIS works well when polygons are intersected by a single straight line, but fails when it is intersected by multiple lines. For example:

[image: No splitting happens if multiple lines intersect 1 polygon]

Ideally, I was expecting that wherever the line intersected, the polygon broke into chunks such that each of the boxes contained the polygon (red) chunks. Are these even possible with QGIS? If so, could somebody suggest a workaround?

Comment: Make sure that your line-layer is dissolved - you can check this while selecting one line with the select feature Tool. If your layer is dissolved, all lines should be selected. If not, use the dissolve algorithm first.